# That which doesn't kill you

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes, word-play

This is a "Hot Network Question" from another site that I thought would make a great question here.

> The Joker: "I believe whatever doesn't kill you, simply makes you stranger." ([Clip from *The Dark Knight* for context](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utEEe97Ir4o))

I think it's a great line, but what does it mean? And how is it *twisted*?

Comment: Isn't it : I believe whatever doesn't kill you, makes you stronger?

Comment: Yes, but my question isn't in error. In other words, you're halfway there. Can you watch the clip?

Comment: Yes,I'll do it. So you mean he says stranger not stronger, don't you? Or you just want the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: Yes, he says _stranger_. So a great answer will say not only what the actual line from the movie means, but also explain the play on words.

Comment: Sure he should say this. Obviously difficulties have made himself so strange. I think it's just a play with the words, and the meaning is simply as what you may get.

Comment: Puns can make interesting questions on ELL, since they often deal with dual meanings of words (though this one deals with near-homophones). I'm glad you mentioned that you were inspired by another SE question. Though some might find such remarks "extraneous", I think such background info adds not only context to a question, but a quaint charm as well. Lastly, I'm not against asking a question designed to give a non-expert a chance for a shot at answering an English question, so long as the questions are true **English** questions (like this one – it's a question about English, not *Batman*).

Comment: I think this is a cool idea! Maybe you should make a question in meta to get ideas, discuss rules etc for future rounds :)

Comment: That's kind of how I got here. I will do it again for the next round.

Comment: Perhaps the "joke" tag could be used for this and similar posts?  Joke: "This tag is for questions about interpreting jokes and understanding humorous wordplay." (@J.R. et al)

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Sure, but I'm not sure that "jokes" applies. "Wordplay", certainly. I don't know if "new" tags are really OK, but I put it in. If it gets deleted, that's fine.

Comment: I like **wordplay**.

Comment: I think this is a great question, but I've removed the part of your edit which contains extra info not relevant to the actual question. You're welcome to being it up in comments, and we've discussed it tangentially on meta :) But the question text isn't the place for it, I'm afraid!

Comment: @WendiKidd  I accept that, especially since the bounty says it, but I do want to be perfectly clear with these kinds of questions. They're not intended to be definitively answered by native English speakers. They're intended to be an opportunity for learners to jump in without fear of saying anything "wrong".

Comment: @Jolenealaska, do you recall if I posted an answer to this?  I thought I did, but don't see it. (I might be thinking of a different post.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my opinion. How do I see the dialogue from the legendary actor.

> ‘Whatever doesn’t kill you, makes you . . . stranger,’ the old proverb is actually derived from Nietzsche *-‘Whatever doesn’t kill you makes you **stronger**’.*

I think Ledger takes it as a kind of pun. The Joker likes to tell stories about how he got the scars and how did he suffer in his childhood. As a kid, he was asked to laugh by his drunken father whilst his mother was being assaulted. The Joker tries to make everybody understand that we all live in **the world of fiction.** 
The Joker builds up stories that manifest not only his indifference to the truths but also his weird thoughts.

The worst things never killed him but made him stronger. BUT, he's a joker, always masked and **thus stranger.** Having this said, the things that don't kill you (the worst circumstances and events in his life) makes (him) you the stranger (the Joker). In simple words, this **deadly strange** face is due to the worst things happened in his life those were fatal but did not kill him leaving him strong, inhuman and cruel.

Comment: @Jolenealaska my pleasure. But thanks for getting me this opportunity to dig in further.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that, as a "twisted" person himself, his view of the world is that anything that harms, but does not kill, warps and corrupts your mind or body until you might as well be dead.

The original phrase ("...makes you stronger.") implies that people get better from being injured. This means the opposite, people change for the worse from injury. They don't die outright, but suffer a kind of "death from a thousand cuts": each suffering moves them slightly from their original self (possibly going back to what they were at birth, the "tabula rasa") until they are effectively dead compared to their original self. Maybe lacking any compassion because they have been victimized too many times, or trust because they have been cheated on and defrauded when trying to love and help. Eventually the original self would, if still alive, be so alienated from what it became it would disown itself as being "dead to me".

Did this answer your question, or did I just ramble nonsense? Let me know and I will revise it.

Comment: That was very well put! One very enthusiastic upvote! I especially like the first line. :)

Answer (score 2):

Huh, I think other answers may be over-analyzing this.

Yes, it's an obvious play on the classic "... makes you stronger". So the Joker is a strange person who exults in his own strangeness, so he deliberately mangles the quote.

Any deeper analysis than that seems to me to be in the "well, maybe, but I doubt the scriptwriter was really thinking that deeply" category.

Comment: Well, complex answers may be kind of over-thinking the issue, but that's not really the point of the question. If you haven't already, read all of the comments or the pre-edit question. +1 anyway, just because your point is perfectly valid.

Comment: I did read all the comments and other answers before posting. And it made my head hurt.